# Webservice desktop communication

Tags: c#, iis

I use visual studio 2010 and i have created a web service in c # That it win32api for use FindWindow and sendmessage commands . When i have tried this webservice on local , from VisualStudio , the precedents commands work, on iis7 the commands don't work. Any idea?

Comment: Web services run on the server. Things like `FindWindow` will operate on the server, not the client. It worked in VS because the client and server are the same machine.

Comment: Ok, and what can i do?

Comment: The only thing you might be able to do is create some kind of browser plug-in. But I don't know enough about that to say if it is possible.

Comment: Both commands should not be called from a webservice. That makes no sense. If you need those commands, you should think about other ways. Why did you use a webservice in the first place?